# Stop macOS VNC server from rendering remote mouse pointer

Tags: remote-desktop, screen-sharing

Currently running macOS 11.2.3, and noticed that the system VNC server (enabled in `System Preference` -> `Screen Sharing`) always includes the mouse pointer in the video feed sent to the client, causing a shadowed mouse pointer on the client side (As VNC viewers would also render the mouse pointer locally to make a smooth motion). And the behavior is the same no matter if I use the `Screen Sharing` as the client on another Mac, or some third party VNC viewers on PC. While the [Vine VNC Server](https://sourceforge.net/projects/osxvnc/) does not have this issue and works perfectly.

So I wonder if there is a way to stop the system default VNC server from rendering the cursor of the remote machine. I have heard the rumors that the $80 Apple Remote Desktop can somehow configure this, but I haven't yet made the investment. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you take the screenshot.

Even with Apple Remote Desktop if you invoke the screenshot on the local Mac it will include the cursor on the remote instance - which has no clue a screenshot is being taken.
If you invoke it on the remote instance the cursor will hide.

If the key commands are the same for both local & remote, then the local instance will launch in preference to the remote.

Comment: oh sorry, by "image" I meant to say the video feed of the remote desktop. VNC sends back remote activities as bitmaps and that's why I used "image". But yeah, it is misleading. so there is no screenshot taking involved.

Comment: Ah, OK, then I've no idea, sorry. I can't even imagine a scenario where you don't want to see the cursor on the remote machine. RDC shows the cursor in both Control & Observe modes, so you probably don't want that. I've never used the basic Screen Sharing though, I've used 'Remote Management' for a decade or more & don't have a machine I can quickly toggle between modes to test, sorry.